# Equivalent to new Date() of mongo shell in python

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm a beginner to mongodb and python, and i'm trying to write python code to delete the documents of multiple collections older than 30 days based on date field which is of NumberLong type and also has to export the collections to CSV before deleting. I'm using below simple code to print the records as a first step by using new Date(). It is working in Mongo Shell but fails in python stating syntax error.please help.

Sample data:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("589d6eb390cc70b775892ae1"), "trgtm" : NumberLong("1486280499661") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("589d602d2fa2fa6687bc7293"), "trgtm" : NumberLong("1486276781059") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("589d701f90cc70b775892ae2"), "trgtm" : NumberLong("1486194463192") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("589d702390cc70b775892ae3"), "trgtm" : NumberLong("1486108067444") }
```

Code

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
conn=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=conn.mydb
col=db.test
query= { "date": { "$lt": new Date(new Date()).getTime() - 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } }
cursor=col.find(query)
slice=cursor[0:100]
for doc in slice:
    print doc
```

Comment: Did you fixed this?

Answer (score 1):

I use datetime for dates in python..

This is an example:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date(2017,2,10)
otherDate = datetime.date(1999,1,1)
date < otherDate # False
```

Comment: @lka8 Thanks, but date needs to be compared with value as shown in the updated post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [datetime.datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) like this:

`query = {"date": {"$lt": datetime.datetime(2021, 6, 14, 0, 0, 0, 0)}}`

To use the current time you can do:

`query = {"date": {"$lt": datetime.now(timezone.utc)}}`

Source: https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/datetimes.html

Answer (score 0):

Use bson.Int64() to query for timestamp in NumberLong format. It worked for me.
Customizing it for you below:

```
import bson
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
conn=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
db=conn.mydb
col=db.test
timestamp_value= <value> #calculate epoch time stamp 30 days earlier and variable should be of type String
query= { "date": { "$lt": bson.Int64(timestamp_value) } }
cursor=col.find(query)
slice=cursor[0:100]
for doc in slice:
    print doc
```